# Android Emulator, the bottom of the screen is black and flickering

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

My Android Emulator is constantly reacting this way. In particular, the bottom of the screen is constantly black. This situation really bothers me. If there is anyone who has encountered this problem before, I would be very glad if it helps.

You can understand the situation better by clicking on the problem article. [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ4GX.gif)